# Jmeter csv data split

Tags: kubernetes, jmeter

I am load testing using Jmeter containers inside k8s cluster.Right now the jmx and the csv files are copied to all the containers.Is there a way to split the data file so that each JMeter instance in container gets its own subset of the original file?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [`split` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) or what? The number of lines in file and the number of pods in cluster can be obtained using [`wc` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wc.1.html)

Also there might be better solutions like using [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/) or [Redis Data Set](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-redis-data-set-an-introduction) so the test data would be stored in a "central" location and you won't have to bother about copying splitting it and copying the parts to the slaves

Comment: Yes I am looking for ways to either split data or have the data in centralized location.So there won’t be any duplication.